# Wrapped Img is not being picked up in JS

Tags: javascript, loops, css-selectors, toggle

I've been stuck on this for a few days. I've tried different selectors and unwrapping the img in the div if that was the problem but no luck. I've been trying to make an accordion.
I'm trying to add a class of "rotate" to the img with the class of "arrow". So that when the question tag is clicked, the arrow img will also rotate.

```js
const questionTag = document.querySelectorAll('.question')

questionTag.forEach(questionTag => {
    questionTag.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (questionTag.classList.contains('open')) {
            questionTag.classList.remove('open');
        } else {
            const questionTagOpen = document.querySelectorAll('.open');

            questionTagOpen.forEach((questionTagOpen) => {
                questionTagOpen.classList.remove('open');
            });
            questionTag.classList.add('open');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.question + .answer {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}


.question.open + .answer {
    display: block;
}


.arrow.rotate {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="question">How many team members can I invite?
    <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="answer">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on 
    team members for the Premium plan.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `[0]` in your code.

The `arrowTag` comes from `document.querySelectorAll()`, which returns a `NodeList`, you need to specify the element from that `NodeList`:

```
var questionTag = document.querySelectorAll('.question')

questionTag.forEach(questionTag => {
    questionTag.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (questionTag.classList.contains('open')) {
            questionTag.classList.remove('open');
        } else {
            const questionTagOpen = document.querySelectorAll('.open');

            questionTagOpen.forEach((questionTagOpen) => {
                questionTagOpen.classList.remove('open');
            });
            questionTag.classList.add('open');
        }
    });



    var arrowTag = document.querySelectorAll('img.arrow')

    questionTag.addEventListener('click', () => {
        arrowTag[0].classList.toggle('rotate'); // missing [0] added here
    });
});
```

The `addEventListener` function is [applied to an event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
Thus, you cannot apply it to the `NodeList`, which is stored in your `arrowTag`:

[image]

Comment: I added the [0] and changed const to var but it is still not adding the class of arrow and/or rotating the arrow when the questionTag is clicked.

Comment: can you update the question with the latest codes?

Comment: Sure. Maybe looking at my whole project will help? I think I'll be following a video I just wanted to see what may be the issue with what I'm doing with my own technique.
https://github.com/FruitySyrup/faq-accordion-card-main